# Magento - Add additional selectable fee's in shopping cart (not products)

Tags: php, shopping-cart, magento

We have a situation where we are looking to allow the user to select specific fee based options they can add to their order, in the shopping cart.

These need to just be additional fee's either percentage based fee's or potentially a fixed rate fee.

We have tried a module that aims to do this, but the functionality is not as well implemented as we had hoped and the code is rather buggy. I feel this may be something that can be done with out the need of a third party module.

The concept could be described as the following:

A user purchases a number of items, they wish to then add priority processing to their order, or priority picking of their products, the main thing is that we may wish to have this based on the total price of the order and based on a percentage if this is possible.

A best case scenario would be to have a piece of code to handle the math and have some arguments to allow the percentages to have switch / case options that way if the the cart total is very low, the percentage would choose a fee based on set criteria and if the cart total is very expensive the same.

We aim to avoid having a static fee as of scenarios where a user picks a small item with a low cost versus a high cost item that requires a great deal more work to process.

Then of course the final potential issue here would be to have this fee added and then labeled in the cart as a line item.

We just rather avoid using simple products to handle this solution.

If any one has any ideas or potential solutions I would greatly appreciate any direction or data you could share.

Thanks in advance!

SFLA99

Comment: I think you need to describe what you are doing for shipping too. With a out-the-box shipping controller you can loop through your basket and determine the 'handling fee' to return a valid rate and label for your shipping method.

Comment: Hey there - did you ever figure this out? I need to do a similar thing (special installation fees, selectable by the customer)... [here's where I'm at currently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12612183/extra-product-fees-in-magento). I'm attempting to add a product to the cart, but I agree, it isn't very elegant... (Also - I assume you're talking about the 'Magik Fees' extesion. yeah... looks a little suspect - glad I didn't buy it...)

Answer (score 0):

It may be tough to do this without some custom code, especially in the cart. The number of ways that you can add to an order's cost in the shopping cart is relatively low.

My suggestion -- depending on how you are handling the actual fulfillment -- would be to add a shipping method (or try to repurpose the existing shipping methods) that depends on the cost of the order. The existing methods typically give you tiers to use (`$25-50 == X cost`, `$51-75 == y cost`, etc), but you could add a custom shipping module that operates on straight percentages. Either way, this would add to the cost of the order quickly and cleanly. The complication is obviously that you need to retain the actual cost of shipping, but that depends on your own internal policies.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Thanks all, let me better clarify, these fees must be selectable by the user on top of their shipping method, as an example, a person may want to select priority picking, maybe we charge $10 for this service, I want the user to be able to select this option and have the item added to the cart total. The trick though is that this item can not be a product as this would add to the line items. We basically want to do something similar to the module (multi-fee's) but keep things cleaner and build it in the system instead of relying on some one else module. Thanks!